# Failed to transform artifact 'kotlin-android-extensions.jar

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, build.gradle, android-jetifier

Getting below error after enabling jetifier

Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/balwinder/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions/1.3.20/b1016507a951b0cfaae431079ec0ac6847d56d8c/kotlin-android-extensions-1.3.20.jar.

```
the given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
```

[image: Dependencies] .

Version

```
def versions = [
        gradlePlugin             : '3.5.1',
        multidex                 : '1.0.3',
        kotlin                   : '1.3.31',

        supportLibrary           : versionDependency.supportLibrary,
        archComp                 : versionDependency.supportLibrary,
        rxJava                   : versionDependency.rxJava,

        constraintLayout         : '1.1.3',

        dataBinding              : '3.1.0-alpha06',

        navigation               : '2.0.0',

        rxKotlin                 : '2.3.0',
        rxAndroid                : '2.1.0',

        dagger                   : '2.22.1',

        retrofit                 : '2.5.0',
        okHttp                   : '3.13.1',
        gson                     : '2.8.5',

        javaxInject              : '1',

        googleServices           : '4.2.0',

        jetifier                 : '1.0.0-beta04',

        glide                    : '4.9.0',


        //Test
        robolectric              : '3.4.2',
        junit                    : '4.12',
        assertj                  : '3.8.0',
        mockitoKotlin            : '1.5.0',
        espresso                 : '3.0.1',
        testRunner               : '1.0.1',

        //lifecycle
        lifecycle                : '2.0.0',

        timber                   : '4.7.1',

        materialComponent        : '1.1.0-alpha07',


        viewPager                : '1.0.0-beta02',

        timber                   : '4.7.1'
]
```